# How to put a screen behind the current one?

Tags: android, screen

I have a app that is started by a received intent (calendar alert).

It may be started multiple times just one after a other (with a few sec between them).

Now i want it to stack the screens from the top down..

So first start of my app gets the view...
if it's fired again while first is still shown..but this one below so when user has handled alert 1 it will show this one..

Thnks..

Answer (score 0):

You may be trying to implement this the wrong way. I would implement a message queue that calls startActivityForResult on the pending intents. If you have more intents to start, add them to the queue. The queue will then show them once the user reacts to the current event.

You might want to take a look at [`IntentService`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/IntentService.html). I've never personally used it, but it might help with what you're looking for.

Comment: hmm..interesting thought..
is there already a mechanism for this queue or do i have to build it completly..

Comment: There is are systems for queueing intents I believe. I'll bet someone else could answer it better. You might try asking a question specifically about that if you have any questions. You could also make your own queue fairly easily with a broadcast receiver and a service

Answer (score 0):

`IntentService` is what you're looking for, it can put Intents into a queue.
My google-fu hasn't been very succesful however on finding a decent example.